# Why does find sometimes match its command line path argument?

Tags: find

On Linux,

```
cd /tmp
mkdir foo; cd foo
```

Now, running

```
find . -name 'foo'
```

gives no output. Whereas running

```
find /tmp/foo -name 'foo'
```

Gives the output `/tmp/foo` which doesn't make sense to me. Can somebody explain
why?

Comment: **find** seaches inside the given path included as it is stated. So if you input `./` it didn't match `foo`

Comment: @Costas: I understand that. What I don't understand is why it has made a difference if I give the absolute path to `find`.

Comment: @York In certain situations there is no behaviour that is always right. Imagine a symlink with the name `bar` that points to a file `foo` which is outside the search path. Shall that match or not?

Comment: The `.` and `/tmp/foo` are not the same - they are two different hard links to the same directory; `find /tmp/foo/. -name 'foo'` doesn't find anything either.

Comment: @jimmij: when I run `find /tmp/foo -name 'foo'`, I was asking bash to find in the directory `/tmp/foo`, a file whose name is "foo". Because the directory `/tmp/foo` is empty, it should have returned nothing. I don't understand why it returns `/tmp/foo`. On the other hand, when I run `find . -name 'foo'`, I was asking bash the same thing, i.e., finding a file in the current directory (which happened to be `/tmp/foo`), whose name is 'foo', and it returns nothing which makes sens.

Comment: When you run `find /tmp/foo -name 'foo'`, I was asking bash to find in the directory `/tmp/foo` with this path/directory included.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`find` traverses the specified directory tree(s), and evaluates the given expression for each file that it finds. The traversal starts at the given path. Here's a summary of how `find . -name foo` operates:

- First path on the command line: `.`

  - Does the base name (`.`) match the pattern `foo`? No, so do nothing.
    It so happens that `/tmp/foo` is another name for the same directory. But `find` doesn't know that (and it isn't supposed to try to find out).
  - Is the path a directory? Yes, so traverse it. Enumerate the entries in `.`, and for each entry, perform the traversal process.

    - The directory is empty: it contains no entry other than `.` and `..`, which `find` does not traverse recursively. So the job is finished.

And `find /tmp/foo`:

- First path on the command line: `/tmp/foo`

  - Does the base name (`foo`) match the pattern `foo`? Yes, so the condition matches.

    - There is no action associated with this condition, so perform the default action, which is to print the path.
  - Is the path a directory? Yes, so traverse it. Enumerate the entries in `/tmp/foo`, and for each entry, perform the traversal process.

    - The directory is empty: it contains no entry other than `.` and `..`, which `find` does not traverse recursively. So the job is finished.

It so happens that `.` and `/tmp/foo` are the same directory, but that's not enough to guarantee that `find` has the same behavior on both. The `find` command has ways to distinguish between paths to the same file; the `-name` predicate is one of them. `find /tmp/foo -name foo` matches the starting directory as well as any file underneath it that's called `foo`. `find . -name .` matches the starting directory only (`.` can never be found during a recursive traversal).

Comment: "it contains no entry other than . and .., which find does not traverse recursively." I assume "does not transverse recursively" refer to "..". If that is correct, then what would "transverse recursively" mean in the context of ".."?

Comment: @FaheemMitha “does not traverse recursively” applies to both `.` and `..`. (If `find` traversed `.` recursively, it would end up going through the directory again and again and again and …) `.` and `..` are not just special notations, they appear as directory entries.

Answer (score 5):

There is no normalization of the command line arguments before the tests are applied. Thus the results differ depending on the used path (if symlinks are involved):

```
cd /tmp
mkdir foo
ln -s foo bar
find /tmp/foo -name foo
find /tmp/bar -name foo
```

In "your case" both calls would give the same result which might be (more) confusing. You can use `-mindepth 1` if you want the starting points ignored (may be non-POSIX).

Comment: `-mindepth 1` works. However, I still don't understand why `find . -name 'foo'` and `find /tmp/foo -name 'foo'` behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

(gnu) find shows any matches found within the path provided to the command because it starts its comparison with the commandline arguments, descending deeper into the directory structure from there (thus, `-maxdepth 0` confines the tests to the base level or the commandline arguments only, whereas `-mindepth 1` skips the commandline arguments as `man find` explains). This is the reason why `find /tmp/foo -name 'foo'` will yield one match even if the directory itself is empty.

`find . -name 'foo'` on the other hand will not yield any result because `.` (dot) is a special file that acts like a hardlink to the same inode as `/tmp/foo` - it is like a seperate (though special) filename and not a symbolic link or an expression that is subjected to pathname expansion by the shell. Therefore, the first test applied by find to the commandline arguments in the given example will not show any matches, since `.` indeed does not match the name pattern defined in `-name 'foo'`. Neither does `/tmp/foo/.` since a test for a `-name` pattern is performed on the basename of the path only (see `man find`), which here again is `.`.

While this behavior may not be expected or appear intuitive from a user perspective (and yes, it had me confused at first as well), it does not constitute a bug but corresponds with the logic and functionality described in the man and info pages for (gnu) find.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried commenting Gilles's answer, but it was too long to fit in a comment. For this reason, I'm putting it as an answer to my own question.

Gilles's explanation (and Shevek's as well) is clear and makes sense. The key point here is that not only does `find` try to match the file names for the files inside the given paths (recursively), but also, it tries to match the base name of the given paths themselves.

On the other hand, is there any proof that this is the way `find` is suppose to work, rather than being a bug? In my opinion, it would be better if it doesn't make the results inconsistent for `find .` and `find ABSOLUTE-PATH` because inconsistency is always confusing and could waste developer a lot of time trying to figure out "what was wrong". In my case, I was writing a script, and the path was taken from a variable. So in order for my script to work properly, what I can think of doing is to write `find $path/. -name 'pattern'`.

Finally, I think getting consistent results for `find` can be achieved by always substituting the `.` with the current directory before proceeding.

Answer (score -1):

There is no object named `foo` in the directory where you started the relative search.

You are correct with assuming that `gfind` is buggy when it reports `/tmp/foo` when using the absolute name as a start directory.

`Gfind` has various deviations from the standard, it seems you found another one. When you like a more standard compliant solution, I recommend `sfind` that is part of the `schilytools`.

`-name` applies to directory search results. None of the two cases you mention will return a directory entry `foo` from a `readdir()` operation.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug too. Here's the output from `find --version`:

    find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
    Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: Well, I checked your example commands with `find` (POSIX certified),  `gfind` and `sfind`; the problem only exists when you use `gfind`. On Linux, `gfind` is not installed under it's native name but under the name `find`.

Comment: It is correct for `find /tmp/foo -name foo` to output `/tmp/foo`. (Cc @York) This is the behavior of OpenBSD `find`, GNU `find`, BusyBox `find`, Solaris `find`, and any other POSIX-compliant `find` (“The primary shall evaluate as true if the basename of the filename being examined matches *pattern* (…)” — when the filename is one that's passed as a path operand, no `readdir` call is involved).